# How to communicate with a running python process from an Objective-C app?

Tags: python, objective-c

I'm building an Objective-C mac app. I'd like that app to be able to start and continuously communicate with the same running python process.

For example, the basic flow might be:

1. App starts, I start a python process in the background
2. The app imports some libraries and initializes some variables in the python process
3. User does something, I run some python code on this python process using the initialized variables and use the result of the python expression in my mac app

What techniques can I use to accomplish this? Any guidance would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to run a mock web service by your Python process. Define your own interfaces (most likely RESTful APIs) for your Objective-C app to access. Maybe it will be a little expensive in performance - it depends on the complexity of your actual task and the amount of data you want to transfer between the two processes.

For example, in Python process, run a standard HTTP service on 8080 port, listening all the time. Then the Obj-C app send a request to localhost, something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_service/start_task
http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_service/get_progress
http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_service/get_result
```

and Python handles that request, do something and return the result in HTTP response.

By the way, maybe you could consider calling Python methods directly by [C interface](http://docs.python.org/c-api/) in your Obj-C app rather than run Python scripts in a seperate process.

Comment: This sounds like a decent approach and may end up being the way I go, but I'm hoping for an easier way to communicate between the running processes. I will accept this answer if there aren't any better suggestions made.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes the simplest way to establish communication between two applications is the client-server protocol **XMLRPC**. Both [Cocoa](http://www.ditchnet.org/xmlrpc/) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/xmlrpc.client.html) do support it.

The Python part is fairly simple:

```
import xmlrpc.client
rpcProxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(URL_OF_SERVER)
rpcProxy.doJobInMacApp(arg1, arg2)
```

As for the Objective-C-part, I don't know, but it seems to be possible: [XML-RPC Server in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909093/xml-rpc-server-in-cocoa) or [Best way to use XML-RPC in Cocoa application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218538/best-way-to-use-xml-rpc-in-cocoa-application)